# display all action dvd in a particular year

Tags: mysql, database

ive made the following table with random data input, I am trying to display all the data with category action and in a particular year.

```
| id_dvd |        title            | category | Years     |
-----------------------------------|----------|-----------|
| 1   |  Bad Neighbours            |comedy    |2012-02-16 |
| 2   |  The Other Women           |comedy    |2014-05-22 | 
| 3   |  The Amazing Spider-Man 2  |action    |2013-06-20 |
| 4   |  Rio 2                     |animation |2014-05-17 |
| 5   |  300                       |action    |2013-02-06 |
| 6   |  Man Of Stel               |action    |2014-11-28 |
| 7   |  Frozen                    |family    |2016-02-18 |
| 8   |  The Immigrant             |romance   |2012-10-03 |
| 9   |  How To Train Your Dragon  |fantasy   |2013-04-21 |
| 10  |  Drama                     |drama     |2015-07-01 |
```

So far this is the query ive come up with. However it dosent show the particular years I want.

```
select * from DVD where category = 'Action' between 2013 and 2014;
```

This is the question supplied -  display all action dvd in a particular year.

If I'm doing this question wrong could you give me a clue as to what im doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: do you get some error? if yes then post that here.

Comment: No errors, just dont display the output I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
select * from DVD where category = 'Action' and YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(Years, "%Y-%m-%d")) between 2013 and 2014;
```

Comment: @user3601263 I posted this answer before Praveen posted. You can see the time

Comment: why do you need to use `STR_TO_DATE()`?

Comment: @Ejay we do not know in advance whether the Years field type is date, timestamp or varchar

Comment: you know it, it is written right there in the question. I think it doesn't matter if it is a `date` or a `varchar` having value in `Y-m-d` format, it'll work. `SELECT YEAR('2012-02-16')` gives `2012`

Comment: @Yes it will work. but if the date value is illegal then what ?

Answer (score 0):

The query itself is wrong! You need to write this way:

```
SELECT * from `DVD`
  WHERE `category` = 'Action'
  AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`Years`, "%d-%m-%Y")) BETWEEN '2013' AND '2014';
```

Comment: that is wrong my friend, just tried that and the 2nd WHERE clause is highlighted in red.

Comment: Okay, will check the syntax once again!

Comment: O you just changed your answer :O

Comment: @user3601263 Please check now... :)

Comment: @Praveen the same answer I given before you

Comment: @www.sblog.in This is a different one!

Comment: Do you realize what `YEAR()` does?

Comment: SELECT * from `DVD`
  WHERE `category` = 'Action'
  AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`Years`, "%Y-%m-%d")) BETWEEN 2013 AND 2014;

Comment: @Ejay Most comments too! LoL. :D

Comment: Why do you need `STR_TO_DATE()`?

Comment: @Ejay not sure if the datatype is varchar or date! That's why for a precaution!